# Can we have a scope parameter while generating OAuth Token to restrict access at an operation level in Azure API Managemen

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, azure-api-management

I have created an API Gateway and It have an API named 'Test Api'. Created an AD for this API and gave permission to 3 users to access test API. Test API have a GET request, POST Request and a DELETE request. I want to create 3 users say user1, user2 and user3. User should have access to all the operations, user2 only for get operations and user 3 only should have access to delete operation should not have access to both GET and POST. How can i limit restrictions to users to access operations in an API. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This should be achievable using `validate-jwt` policy at the `operation` level. Here is a [demo](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/videos/episode-177-more-api-management-features-with-vlad-vinogradsky/) about how to use the Validate JWT policy to pre-authorize access to operations based on token claims.

For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-access-restriction-policies#ValidateJWT).